# Integer ratio from non-integer ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two non-integer numbers, and I need to find a factor I can multiply them both by to produce an integer ratio that has the same quotient as the two reals. Is this possible for all pairs of reals, and if so, how can it be done?

i.e. $
1 : 0.5 \rightarrow 2 : 1\\ 
0.5 : 0.625 \rightarrow 4:5\\
...
$

Comment: "*Is this possible for all pairs of reals?*"  No.  Consider $\sqrt{2}:1$.  "*Is this possible for all pairs of* **rationals**?"  Yes.  Suppose your rationals are $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ where each of $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $b,d$ are nonzero.  Then the ratio $\frac{a}{b}:\frac{c}{d}$ is the same as the ratio $ad:bc$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two numbers, call them $a$ and $b$ are both rationals, then be definition this is doable.  By definition $a = \frac mn$ for some integers $m,n$ and $b = \frac pq$ for some integers $p,q$.  Therefore $\frac ab = \dfrac {\frac mn}{\frac pq}=\frac {mq}{np}$  and then numbers you want are $mq:np$ is the same proportion as $a:b$.

If one of the numbers is irrational, the other one must be a rational multiple of the same irrational number.  That is if $a = w$ and $w$ is irrational.  Than $b = kw$ where $k$ is rational.  Note: $b = kw  =v$ is also irrational and $a = \frac 1k v$ so *both* numbers are irrational and each are an irrational of the other.  In this case $\frac ab = k$ and as $k$ is rational *by definition* $k = \frac mn$ for some integers $m,n$ and $m:n$ is the same propertion as $a:b$.

In any other case, either one is irrational and the other rational-- or both irrational but not rational multiples of the other, then this is impossible.

Basically, being able to find integer proportions *is* what being rational means.

Now I think what you are actually asking is how given say $0.7$ and $\frac 23$ how do you *find* the numbers?  Well....  being rational means those numbers must exist.  And those numbers are the definition of the rational numbers.  So it's not really a matter of figureing them out.  If you know what $0.7$ *is* you must have some sense that $0.7 = \frac mn = \frac 7{10}$ and $\frac 23 = \frac 23$.  Then the integer ratio comes by multiply out the denominators:  $\frac 7{10}: \frac 23$ is propotional to $\frac 7{10}*10*3:\frac 23*10*3$ is proportional to $21:20$.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only if they are integer multiples of a third party real number i.e.$$a=kx\\b=lx\\k,l\in\Bbb Z,x\in\Bbb R$$